# rand numbers with arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, zend-framework

I want to implement a random numbers for arrays, let's see if I make my self clear on this:

I have

```
$array[0] = 'Hello';
$array[1] = 'Good Morning';
$array[2] = 'Good Afternoon';
$array[3] = 'Good Night';
$array[4] = 'Bye';
```

I have this way because it's the way my boss want it tis way, instead of array(1=>'Hello', etc etc. Anyway what I want is to make a random numbers into the arrays, $array[random number], using the functionality rand('0','99') as an example.

Maybe doing this:

```
$rand1 = rand('0','99');
$array['$rand1'] = 'Hello';
```

Will this work?, anyone has a better idea or please help me find a soluton for this?

Thanks

Comment: Why not try it? You need to remove the single quotes around `$rand1` in the last line, though, i.e. `$array[$rand1] = 'Hello';`.

Answer (score 3):

> Will this work?

No. Random != Unique. If the same number is produced more than once, you will overwrite the existing array element.

You have not stated why you want this, but if you're looking for a random order for your array, you can use [shuffle](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php).

If you need to grab a random element from an array, you can use [array_rand](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php).

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do can be simplified as follows:

```
// this is the same as creating an array: $array[0] = 'Hello'; $array[1] = 'Good Morning';
$array = array('Hello', 'Good Morning', ...etc...);

// array_rand will give you a random "key" from the array
echo $array[array_rand($array, 1)];
```

Some resources which will be of assistance dissecting this: [`array_rand()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) and [PHP's page on arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array_rand`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php)..  Your technique will work similarly, assuming you use the length of the array as the maximum (and you know the minimum).

Answer (score 0):

Don't go for rand(0,99) as u will run onto errors.. since your array length is just 5.

Try this.

```
<?php
$array[0] = 'Hello';
$array[1] = 'Good Morning';
$array[2] = 'Good Afternoon';
$array[3] = 'Good Night';
$array[4] = 'Bye';

shuffle($array);

for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++)
  {
    echo($array[$i]);
    echo("<br>");
  }

?>
```

Comment: I think he want to assign array key with random number, not to select from array randomly.

Comment: Right Dipu Raj, what I want to do is this: give a random number to each array, what I'm trying to do is extracting all data from a db in a array, so whenever it click or refresh the browser it will always show a different parametrs, is like a quiz for kids, they need to match if the sentences matches the time.

Comment: @JMR, Have you tried Shuffle ?  I have edited the example. Each and every refresh you will have elements in different order. Check the example.

Comment: I don't get anything, just break html tag :(